# How can I use my methods without setting the data as a parameter/argument in them?

Tags: java

I am creating a LinkedList of sorts without actually importing LinkedList.   One thing I have never understood as many times as I read it or it is explained to me is how you can create a method and tack it onto the end of something, an array for example, and it works with the array.  When I first started programming, I would just create the method with the perameters that I needed in it, then call it with the argument that I was manipulating.  I am having trouble with my print() and my findMax() because I iterate through those to do what needs to be done, but without calling print/findMax with the array in its parenthesis, I am not sure how to do it.  I put my code below so hopefully my question will make more sense.

```
public class LListIter implements LListIterIF {
    private Node head;

    public LListIter() {
        head = null;
    }

    public void append(int dx) {
        Node rpx;
        
        if (head == null) {
            rpx = new Node(dx);
            head = rpx;
            return;
        }
    
        Node parent = head;
        Node child = parent.getNext();
        
        while (child != null) {
            parent = parent.getNext();
            child = child.getNext();
        }
        
        rpx = new Node(dx);
        parent.setNext(rpx);
    }
    

    public void print(String msg) {
        System.out.println(msg);
        System.out.println(data);
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(data[i]);
        }
    }

    public int findMax() {
        int max = data[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
            if (data[i] > max) {
                max = data[i];
            }
        }
        return max;
    }

    public void delete(int dx) {
        Node temp = head; 
        Node prev = null;
 
        // If head needs to be deleted
        if (temp != null && temp.getData() == dx) {
            head = temp.getNext(); // Changed head
            return;
        }
 
        // Search for the int that gets deleted
        while (temp != null && temp.getData() != dx) {
            prev = temp;
            temp = temp.getNext();
        }
 
        // if it cant be found in the list
        if (temp == null) {
            System.out.println("Cannot Find Integer To Be Deleted");
            return;
        }
        // Delete the Node?
        prev.setNext(temp.getNext());
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LListIter data = new LListIter();
        data.append(1);
        data.append(2);
        data.append(3);
        
        data.print("Start");

    }

}
```

The class implements LListIterIF, but that class just has the methods in it.  My problem lies in that I do not understand how to call on the object I created in the main method so that I may use it in the methods up above.  Before I would have done it as print(data) and made the method parameters so that it would accept it.  I am not sure how to access the information that I need in this case.

Comment: These two sections from Oracle's Java tutorials on [object methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/usingobject.html) and [static (class) mehods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) should help. I recommend you read the entire chapter.

Answer (score 0):

### Assuming Node's getData should be printed

### update print method

Assuming the requirement is to print the contents of the list in the order from head, the print method should be modified as

```java
  public void print() {    
    for (Node current = head; current != null; current = current.getNext()) {
      System.out.println(current.getData());
    }
  }
```

### invoke the print method on data object

```java
  data.print()
```

### Append could be modified

```java
    public void append(int dx) {        
        if (head == null) {
            head = new Node(dx);
            return;
        }

        Node current = head;
        while (current.getNext() != null) {
          current = current.getNext();
        }
    
        current.setNext(new Node(dx));
    }
```